# Updating state array of objects from api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Hy, let me explain my problem, i have a state of tag called tag_data :

```
const  [tagData, setTagData] = useState([
    { key: '1', label: 'Music', active: 0 },
    { key: '2', label: 'Sport', active: 0 },
    { key: '3', label: 'Dance', active: 0 },
    { key: '4', label: 'Cook', active: 0},
    { key: '5', label: 'Video Games', active: 0},
    { key: '6', label: 'Travel', active: 0 },
    { key: '7', label: 'Picture', active: 0 },
    { key: '8', label: 'Animals', active: 0 },
    { key: '9', label: 'Coding', active: 0},
    { key: '10', label: 'Party', active: 0},
])
```

I do a api call for get ACTIVE tag from my user :

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
       setLoad(true)
       try {
           const result = await axios.post('/user/activetag')
           console.log(result.data.active_tag)
            setTagData({
                   // update
            })
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
       }
       setLoad(false)
   }
   fetchData()
}, [])
```

Then the result store the active tags like this :

```
active_tag: Array(5)
0: {tag_id: 1, label: "Music"}
1: {tag_id: 2, label: "Sport"}
2: {tag_id: 3, label: "Dance"}
3: {tag_id: 4, label: "Cook"}
4: {tag_id: 5, label: "Video Games"}
```

I would like to update the tagData state and put active to 1 where the tag_id is equal to the key of tagData state, any idea ?

Full code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';
import axios from 'axios'
import Loading from '../../../../Loading/Loading'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // style
 })
export default function TagUser(){
const classes = useStyles();
const [load, setLoad] = useState(false)
const  [tagData, setTagData] = useState([
    { key: '1', label: 'Music', active: 0 },
    { key: '2', label: 'Sport', active: 0 },
    { key: '3', label: 'Dance', active: 0 },
    { key: '4', label: 'Cook', active: 0},
    { key: '5', label: 'Video Games', active: 0},
    { key: '6', label: 'Travel', active: 0 },
    { key: '7', label: 'Picture', active: 0 },
    { key: '8', label: 'Animals', active: 0 },
    { key: '9', label: 'Coding', active: 0},
    { key: '10', label: 'Party', active: 0},
])

useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
       setLoad(true)
       try {
           const result = await axios.post('/user/activetag')
           console.log(result.data)
           setTagData({
                   // update
            })
        } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
       }
       setLoad(false)
   }
   fetchData()
}, [])


const handleDelete = (key) => {
    //delete
}
const handleSubmit = (key) => {
    //submit
}

if(load){
    return <Loading/>
} else {
return(
    <Paper variant="outlined" square component="span" className={classes.root}>
       {
           tagData.map((data) => {
               if (data.active === 0) {
                   return (
                       <li key={data.key}>
                           <Chip
                               variant="outlined"
                               color="secondary"
                               label={data.label}
                               className={classes.chip}
                               onDelete={() => handleSubmit(data.key)}
                               deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />} 
                           />
                       </li>
                   )
               } else {
                   return (
                       <li key={data.key}>
                           <Chip
                               color="secondary"
                               label={data.label}
                               className={classes.chip}
                               onDelete={() => handleDelete(data.key)}
                           />
                       </li>
                   )
               }
           })
       }
   </Paper>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Would you be open to using a small 3rd-party library if it simplifies your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>**[Disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):** I am the author of the [suspense-service](https://github.com/patrickroberts/suspense-service) library used in this answer.</sub>

If you're open to using a 3rd-party library, it can significantly simplify your data-fetching logic. You won't need a `load` state, or a `useEffect()`, the component will only render when the list is ready:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';
import axios from 'axios';
import { createService, useService } from 'suspense-service';
import Loading from '../../../../Loading/Loading';

const defaultTags = [
  { key: '1', label: 'Music', active: 0 },
  { key: '2', label: 'Sport', active: 0 },
  { key: '3', label: 'Dance', active: 0 },
  { key: '4', label: 'Cook', active: 0},
  { key: '5', label: 'Video Games', active: 0},
  { key: '6', label: 'Travel', active: 0 },
  { key: '7', label: 'Picture', active: 0 },
  { key: '8', label: 'Animals', active: 0 },
  { key: '9', label: 'Coding', active: 0},
  { key: '10', label: 'Party', active: 0},
];

const UserActiveTags = createService(async (allTags) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post('/user/activetag');

    console.log(result.data.active_tag);

    const activeTags = result.data.active_tag.map((tag) => tag.tag_id);
    const activeTagsSet = new Set(activeTags);

    return allTags.map((tag) => ({
      ...tag,
      active: activeTagsSet.has(tag.key) ? 1 : 0
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return allTags;
  }
});

export default function TagUser() {
  return (
    <UserActiveTags.Provider request={defaultTags} fallback={<Loading />}>
      <TagList />
    </UserActiveTags.Provider>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // style
}));

function TagList() {
  const { root, chip } = useStyles();
  const tagData = useService(UserActiveTags);

  const handleDelete = (key) => {
    //delete
  };
  const handleSubmit = (key) => {
    //submit
  };

  const tagList = tagData.map(({ active, key, label }) => {
    const props = active === 0
      ? { variant: 'outlined', onDelete: () => handleSubmit(key), deleteIcon: <DoneIcon /> }
      : { variant: 'default', onDelete: () => handleDelete(key) };

    return (
      <li key={key}>
        <Chip
          color="secondary"
          label={label}
          className={chip}
          {...props}
        />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Paper variant="outlined" square={true} component="span" className={root}>
      {tagList}
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

If you need `tagData` to be stateful, then

```
const tagData = useService(UserActiveTags);
```

needs to be updated to this:

```
const initialTagData = useService(UserActiveTags);
const [tagData, setTagData] = useState(initialTagData);

useEffect(() => {
  setTagData(initialTagData);
}, [initialTagData]);
```

Comment: your lib seem interseting i will try it ;)

Comment: @YanDbz do your `handle...` functions call `setTagData()`? If so, I need to slightly edit my answer to accomodate that. It will only be a minor edit though.

Comment: yes he does, i only change the active to 0 at 1 or 1 to 0 again

Answer (score 0):

I think you could something like this,

In your useEffect(),

```
const result = await axios.post('/user/activetag');
const filteredTags = tagData.map((e) => {
    const checkActive = result.data.some(i => i.tag_id == e.key);
    if(checkActive){
      const temp = {...e};
      temp.active = 1;
      return temp;
    }
   return e;
});

setTagData(filteredTags);
```

Hope that works!

Comment: That would cause an infinite loop because rules of hooks would require `tagData` to be a dependency of the `useEffect()` with this approach.

Comment: Nop :/, it pull al active to 1, when i log filteredTags, btw result.data.some is my result.data.active_tag.map() ?

Comment: it works too i changed result.data.some(/* */) by result.data.active_tag.find(/* */)